# how to navigate to firefox browser from phonegap application

Tags: phonegap

I have to display a website on a android mobile browser, But the issue is that the website is supported only on the firefox browser, Is there a way in phonegap to navigate the website link to a firefox browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know; you can make the app compatible cross browser and avoid this issue.

If you plan to move ahead with your existing code then this url might help you out: http://tannerburson.com/blog/2012/05/28/IntentChooser-my-first-PhoneGap-Cordova-plugin/